# Recursive Sequences codes

Tags: java, math, recursion, logic, sequence

I am quite new to Java programming and was wondering how do I code for a recursive sequence. I've come across 2 questions that probably involves it and sort of understand what it works. What I am having trouble with is how to apply it into codes.

Q1) Sequence 1:

```
a_1=1 
a_n=1/2 * a_(n-1) , for n>1
```

Sequence 2:

```
b_1=a_1 
b_n=b_(n-1)+a_n
```

How do I code it to find any term in Sequence 2?

Q2) Plan B offers an annual interest of `0.2%` of the amount deposited in the current year and `0.1%` of the amount deposited two years back. Plan B will give `0.3%` only for the first year of deposit. If Mr Song deposits `$100,000`, how long will he take to reach `$1000,000`, without taking out his deposit at all?
So far, I managed to find the Recursive formula to be as `A_n = 1.002 * An-1 + 0.001 * A_n-3` where `A_0 = 0, A_1 = 100 000, A_2 = 100300, and A_3 = 100500.60`

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Yes, I did try it myself first before asking but it's my first try coding a recursive sequence so it didn't turn out well.

Comment: Don't make question with two problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write sequence definition in code (I used pseudocode)

```
 int a(n) {
 if (n==1) 
    return 1
 else  //optional
    return a(n-1) / 2
 }
```

Is it clear now how to write b(n)?